# DJANGO: I have been trying do calculation in Views and call function whenever i click on a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have been trying to make calculations using django but I keep on hitting different errors. the latest one was Base 10 error in django.

VIEWS.PY

```
def subs(request, pk):
    sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values('sessions').first()
    sw_list =  sw
    sw_lists = sw +1
    return JsonResponse(sw_lists, safe=False)
```

MODEL.PY

```
class Swimmers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    idno = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    sessions = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    totalsessions = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False )
    dateofpayment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)
    date_from = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_to = models.DateField(null=True)
    type_choice = (
        ("basic", "Basic"),
        ("3x1 week", "3x1 Week"),
        ("1 session", "1 Session"),
        ("2x1", "2x1"),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True, 
        choices=type_choice, default=type_choice)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=True)
    registration = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    keenphone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

URLS.PY

```
path('swimminglist/', views.SWGIndex.as_view(), name="swimminglist"),
path('create/', views.SWGCreateView.as_view(), name='create_swimmer'),
path('update/<int:pk>', views.SWGUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_swimmer'),
path('read/<int:pk>', views.SWGReadView.as_view(), name='read_swimmer'),
path('delete/<int:pk>', views.SWGDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_swimmer'),
path('subt/<int:pk>', views.subs, name='subt'),
```

Thank You For The Help And Support Much Appreciate It. Have A Blessed Day You All.

Comment: The reason why people have downvoted your question is because it is unclear. You're just throwing code at the community, saying that you get different errors, and ask for help. The community here generally likes questions that are more targeted and show an effort on the part of the one asking the question to trouble-shoot.

Comment: I believe the question is clear - DJANGO: I have been trying do calculation in Views and call function whenever i click on a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thing I see in your code is you are not checking if the record you are looking for exists or not you can do something like this:

```
if sw:
    sw_list =  sw
    sw_lists = sw +1
```

or the better way is:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
 ...
sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers,id=pk).sessions
```

If it doesn't work please post a complete block of your error